# Why does multiple variable assigment work for a quick sort algorithm but not for line by line assignment?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Basically trying to understand why doing a multiple variable assignment for a quick sort implementation works, like follows:

```
if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
    a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]
```

But not doing it line by line, like so:

```
if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
    a_list[i] = a_list[i+1]
    a_list[i+1] = a_list[i]
```

Here is the full code if it helps:

```
def bubble_sort(a_list):
    last_ind = len(a_list) - 1
    flag = True
    
    while flag:
        flag = False
        for i in range(0, last_ind):
            if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
                a_list[i], a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1], a_list[i]
                flag = True
                
    return a_list
    
    
a_list = [5,8,2,1]
print(bubble_sort(a_list))
```

Comment: Is this not obvious?  After doing `a_list[i] = a_list[i+1]` by itself, you've permanently lost the previous value of `a_list[i]`.  Doing `a_list[i+1] = a_list[i]` afterwards is pointless, because you're assigning the value that just came from `a_list[i+1]`.  Using a temporary variable, or Python's fairly unique `A, B = B, A` is required to actually swap the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first implementation, behind the scenes python will create a tuple to store the values of both variables, then will change the values of the variables.

In the second implementation after the value of `a_list[i]` is changed, the previous value is lost, so there is no way to set `a_list[i+1]` to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks this was the less obvious part I was trying to understand about Pythons behind the scenes operation. I thought they were somehow equivalent to one another. Isnt it like this in Java too? So basically when we do a multiple variable assignment it creates temporary memory to do the swap whereas the second version, the value is being changed which then alters the second value being changed. Is it that multiple variable assignment is INSTANTANEOUS, whereas the second example is manual?

Answer (score 0):

Say `a, b= 1, 2`. Essentially it does tuple unpacking such that the values on the left (tuple) get assigned the value of the corresponding element on the right side (tuple).

So e.g. the above exame implies `(a, b) = (1, 2)`  which in turn implies `a=1` and `b=2`

Now assume that `a=5` and `b=10'

```
a = 5
b = 10

# Right method
a, b = b, a    # same as saying (a, b) = (10, 5) and thus assigning a = 10 and b = 5

# Wrong method
a = b        # a is now assigned 10
b = a        # a is 10 from the previous line, and b is now assigned 10
```

I wouldnt say that the first method is instantaneous and the second is manual, but rather they do two different things. One of them is unpacking a tuple of values (which happened to be stored in variables) into a tuple of variables while the other is just i guess errored variable assignment.

One way to make the second method work would be

```
c = a   # new variable stores value of a
a = b   # a is reassigned to the value of b
b = c   # b is now reassigned to the original value of a (which was previously stored in c)
```

Answer (score -1):

The example

```py
a_list[i] = a_list[i+1]
a_list[i+1] = a_list[i]
```

will modify the value at index `i` in `a_list`, then set index `i + 1` to that modified value. You can think of the multiple assignment syntax as Python doing both assignments at the same time, so one assignment wouldn't affect the other.

Comment: It's rather important that multiple assignment does *not* happen at the same time. Specifically, that is why this even works: the right hand side is guaranteed to be evaluated first.

Comment: I think I'm failing to see why setting both values to the right hand side at the same time is different from what you're saying.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think I understand it better now, it is not that it is happening at the same time/simultaneously, it is that there is a kind of TEMPORARY MEMORY that comes up where the data is stored in a tuple for the first variable assignment without altering the other variable. So effectively alerting the first will have no effect on the second assignment because there is temporary memory in a tuple for both operations? Is this right?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi And I suppose after that operation finishes the indexes, a_list[i] and a_list[i+1] are going to  point at the temporary tuple data [i+1] and temporary tuple data [i] respectfully. Curious if this creates a deep copy or shallow copy of the data?